# Dot vs. Pixel - rudimentary explanation

Tags: terminology, pixel, dpi

I've read many explanations, but either they all are too abstruse or they gainsay each other.

[Why Dots Per Inch Isn't Pixels Per Inch](https://tedium.co/2018/01/18/dots-per-inch-pixels-per-inch/)

> A dot refers to ink density, effectively; a pixel refers to image density on a screen.

Well what does "density" mean?

[A quick PSA on "dots" versus "pixels" in LCDs | TechCrunch](https://techcrunch.com/2010/07/21/a-quick-psa-on-dots-versus-pixels-in-lcds/)

> It’s actually pretty simple: LCDs are made up of pixels, and pixels are made up of dots.

[joojaa's answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/77745) is similar.

> No, each pixel is represented by multiple dots*.

But [Scott](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/77746) gainsaid all this.

> There is absolutely *zero* correlation between pixels and dots. None.

Then I tried [Alan Gilbertson's answer.](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6080/what-is-the-difference-between-dpi-dots-per-inch-and-ppi-pixels-per-inch)

> A **pixel** (the word was originally coined, iirc, by IBM and derives from "picture element") is the smallest indivisible unit of information in a digital image. Pixels may be displayed, or they may be printed, but you can't divide pixels into smaller pieces to get more information. `How many channels and bits per channel make up one pixel` is the measure of how subtle the information in a pixel may be, but the basic fact is that 1 pixel the smallest increment of information in an image. If you do video, you know that pixels don't have to be square -- they are non-square in all older video formats. Square or not, a pixel is still the smallest unit of a picture.

The sentence colored in gray addled me. What are "channels" and "bits per channel"?

> An **inch** (okay, so you know this already -- bear with me) is a unit of linear measurement on a surface, which could be a screen or a piece of paper.
>
> A **dot** is, well, a dot. It can be a dot on a screen, or it can be a dot produced by a printhead. Like pixels, dots are atomic. They're either there, or they're not. How much fine detail a screen can display depends on how close the dots are (what they used to call "dot pitch" in the old CRT days). How small the dots are from an inkjet, a laser printer or an imagesetter determines how much fine detail it can reproduce.

What does "atomic" mean? I feel I need to know some physics to understand this answer!

[Rafael's answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/102900) is the least abstruse, but it still refers to recondite terms like "the bit depth".

Comment: For a display, the term 'dot-pitch' just rolls off the tongue better than 'pixel-pitch'. In the early days of computing, everybody knew what a dot was, but not necessarily what a pixel was… so the marketing guys came up with a buzz-word, rather than an unambiguous description. We're still suffering from this early  misconception to this day, when people still think an image file can have a dpi… it can't. It doesn't get a dpi until it's actually printed. Until then, all it has is dimensions in pixels.

Comment: You don't need to know some physics, you just need to know some Greek! Atomic comes from a- tomos, which means "not cuttable", "indivisible." From Greek tmein, to cut.

Comment: @DavidConrad: indeed; this usage of "atomic" is common in computing, for example in lock-free operations like C++11 `std::atomic`, and database transactions (either fully happens or not at all, and other queries can't see an in-between state).  [Can num++ be atomic for 'int num'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39393850) / https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)

Comment: It's worth noting that modern text rendering (on a screen) often uses "sub-pixel" elements.  On a screen, a single pixel is typical made up of a triad of Red, Green and Blue (for lack of a better word) dots (sorry, different meaning) or stripes.  Sub-pixel rendering takes advantage of the geometry of those sub-pixel elements to achieve a better degree of _anti-aliasing_.  Take a look at ClearType: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/cleartype/

Comment: @4less Might it help to keep all the details on hold and first establish beyond doubt, two things: First that the levels of detail in images and the paper/screens/whatever they're displayed on are not related? Then that even if there is an international, interspecialist agreement on terminology, there's no guarantee that whoever we're talking to will use the same language?

Comment: @4less After that, broadly, dots are (prolly) the smallest details in the image itself, depending on the magnification used by the artist or the viewer… another "helpful" complexity!

Meanwhile pixels are the smallest areas of detail the paper/screens/whatever they're displayed on are capable of distinguishing, depending only on the factory definition and. nothing to do with either artist or viewer…

Comment: @Tetsujin The term "dot pitch" is associated with colour CRT displays; [dot pitch](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/154702/147841) and pixel pitch are different things. A single pixel generally lights multiple dots of phosphor on the screen.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*(It's clear now that a simple answer to this question doesn't exist. Our language simply isn't precise enough. I like the two other answers, but would still like to give an answer seen more from the viewpoint of a graphic designer.)*

A **pixel** is simply the smallest unit of an image. An image file is a collection of pixels. Nothing more than colored squares in a grid. The pixels don't have a physical size until you assign one to them and they are not necessarily the same as the pixels you see on a monitor. It depends on how you choose to display them. They are to be seen as an *abstract* idea. Pure information.

You might be making pixel art for a game. So you design your graphics by coloring a grid of pixels. But when you display the graphics, you probably scale it up several times. On the *design level*, your pixel character can still be said to consist of for example 7×12 pixels even though it might be taking up 28×48 pixels *on the screen*.

[image]

So we live with different meanings of the word "pixel".

Likewise, when working with design for print, a pixel in itself have no meaning in a physical sense. In vector layout applications, you often place images at different resolutions in the same document. You can even rotate or stretch the images.

[image]

In this (very ugly) collage from InDesign, because we have defined a physical size for each image, the four images now have each their own resolution measured in *PPI* (pixels per inch). The stretched image where the pixels aren't square have a different resolution horizontally and vertically.

A **dot** is, for a graphic designer, a less ambiguous term. It's the smallest square a printing device can print. Unlike a pixel, a dot *does* have a physical size although it differs from device to device.

Most (if not all) printing devices can only print *solid* inks. Either there is color applied or there isn't. Like an old-fashioned stamp. So they need to have a rather high resolution of dots to be able to make some kind of pattern to create the *illusion* of different colors.

For example the offset machine we have at my job use printing plates that has a resolution of 2400 *DPI* (dots per inch). When a document is sent to the so-called *RIP* (raster image processor), it creates a 1-bit image of each CMYK channel. The tints of the original pixels are interpreted into different densities of *halftone screen*. These patterns are made of dots.

[image]

**Note that the circles of the halftone screen are *not* what we talk about when we say "dots". The dots are the square elements which the circles consist of. Of course they are saved as pixels in an image file, but at this stage of production we still refer to them as dots.**

Below is a close-up of part of the collage from above after being interpreted by a RIP. It shows all four CMYK channels layered on top of each other. The original pixels are sort of used as masks for the halftone raster. It's one big messy soup of pixels at different PPI, normalized into halftone raster at one specific DPI.

[image]

The 1-bit images of each channel are burned onto printing plates and thereby the dots become physical. Ink is applied to the plates and then pressed onto paper. So the dots are directly transferred to paper, but the original pixels are long gone.

(I'm focusing on offset print as its my expertise. On a digital printer like an inkjet, the process is different but more or less follows the same principle.)

Comment: This is very close to the perfect answer. This should be the accepted answer

Comment: What's still unclear is the color relation: A pixel is definitely colored, while a dot on paper or even on screen may consist of multiple dots to represent one colored pixel. So IMHO there is no 1:1 relationship between on pixel and on dot; it's more like a 1:n (one pixel represented by multiple dots).

Comment: @U.Windl, there might be a typo in your comment, but dots can't be said to consist of dots. They are the smallest unit. They do not really "exist" on screen. They are displayed only for preview purposes as pixels in pure black or the color of the ink used for print, but they are to be seen as "printing instructions" for the device. They do not as such "have" a color. In offset printing they end up as a tiny square on the printing plate that can hold ink. The plate itself does not "know" which ink will be applied.

Comment: @U.Windl, about the relationship between dots and pixels: I've tried to show how a print PDF can have images with multiple resolutions and that pixels can even be rotated. So the print PDF can have many different sizes of pixels. All these pixel grids don't align to each other or to the grid of dots or even to the grid of the halftone. It's hard to simplify it because it's not that simple. The original pixels are simulated by halftone screening which is made of dots.

Comment: So a printer really doesn't print any other real color apart from C, M, Y and K? All other colors are mere illusion? 

Earlier I had believed that printer mixes C, M, Y and K in proper ratio to create another color. But what you've described makes my belief incorrect.

Comment: Also, since pixel is not a physical thing, what do we call one dot in a screen (laptop)? Casually I would always say screen consists of pixel and pixels become dead in old screen.

Comment: Yes @Vikas, ordinary printers can only print *solid* colors. (Some special printers might exist which I don't know about.). If you look at printed material with a magnifying glass, you will most likely see a pattern of some sort. This is one of the reasons for sometimes choosing to print with spot colors (like Pantone) because then you can get solid, smooth colors without pattern. But only in that specific color. See my comparison between the brown colors [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/144720).

Comment: @Vikas, I simply just think that our language is lacking some precision here. The word "pixel" is *both* used for the tiny physical square on your monitor *and* for the abstract idea of a square "picture element".

Comment: @Wolff yes I've seen those imperfect colors on cheap printed stickers, perhaps on matchboxes sometimes. So Pantone prints real color? Suppose if there's Pantone brown/pink/skyblue color, it wouldn't mix some colors but actually uses real colors and prints things?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131463/discussion-between-wolff-and-vikas).

Comment: @Wolff About the "typo": Actually it was intentional: The text said (the equivalent of) a dot is the smallest drop of ink on the paper, but I contrasted it with a "color dot" that consists of multiple single-color-dots (e.g.: CMYK). I got the impression that print resolution is so "low" because of that.

Comment: @U.Windl, yeah it's confusing that "dots" are used to create ... well "halftone dots". Would be easier if we could call the latter "circles" or something to able to differentiate. In offset print a dot isn't really a "drop" of ink. It's a square area like you see in the preview on screen. In my example a 1/2400 inch x 1/2400 inch square. I think I lost the thread here. Do you still have a question? 

Comment: This may be getting off topic, but the obvious (to this casual outsider) followup question is why the "halftone dots" are so big (so many pixels), much higher than the 2400PPI resolution would appear to allow.  Is making them at such a coarser scale necessary for physical durability of the print plate over a run, or is it more about being able to finely vary the spacing to get different visual intensities without making the pattern irregular?  e.g. exactly half could be done with a checkerboard pattern of 2400PPI dots, but other regular patterns that tile the plane are different avg. density.

Comment: If there's any simple explanation for that (or a link that explain it), it would be cool to throw that into your answer when you introduce the concept of halftone dots.  If there's some standard connection between their size and the PPI of the printing machine, that would somewhat relate those two resolutions perhaps?  Or that's probably going to be more confusing to bring up for people that aren't already thinking about half-tone dot pitch as some kind of resolution.

Comment: @PeterCordes, I think adding this information to the answer would be too much. It's a big subject. But in short: You are on the right track. A checkerboard pattern of tiny 2400 PPI dots would not be durable and you can't be sure that every single dot would be transferred to the paper. Besides that there is the issue called *dot gain*. When the ink hits the paper it bleeds out a bit. So a 50% checkerboard pattern would just become all black. The halftone pattern needs to have a certain frequency (measured in *LPI* - lines per inch) so this doesn't happen.

Comment: This frequency is different on different papers. The more uncoated and coarse the paper is, the bigger the pattern. The ideal is to have completely round halftone circles like before the digital age where the pattern was analogue. A high DPI is needed partly to be able to make the halftone circles seem round to the human eye and partly to be able to make the size of the circles vary in small increments. Hope this clears things up a bit. 

Comment: Ah right, ink bleed on paper, forgot about that part of the physical world :P  I think I'd read about that before at some point.  Thanks.  Agreed that's more explanation than belongs in an answer, but perhaps something like "(which are larger than pixels so they can be round and have controlled spacing, and for physical paper/ink reasons)" could be snuck in somewhere if you want, or just here in comments is fine.

Comment: Minor nitpick: Pixels and dots are not really little squares, even though graphics software sometimes confusingly likes to display them as such. The truth is [a little more complicated](http://alvyray.com/Memos/CG/Microsoft/6_pixel.pdf).

Comment: @ComicSansMS, thanks for the link! That's interesting to me *personally* (not least because I dabble a bit with WebGL at the moment and it helps to think like this). But I would argue that for most graphic designers it makes more sense to regard pixels as squares. They look like squares and behave like squares, both in our graphical applications, on screen and on print. Graphic designers are in the end mostly concerned about how things are perceived. Background knowledge is always good of course, but I can't really see how this "points in a grid" model could affect a design decision.

Comment: @Wolff The more crucial point of that paper is that the point samples are always perceived through a reconstruction filter and squares are a really bad model for how this works in practice. So if for instance, you are worried about how a sharp border between two colors will look like in print, the squares model will not be a good predictor. I guess most artists have a good intuition for the different reconstruction filters for print, screen display, etc. The paper attempts to formalize that intuition in a more mathematical way.

Answer (score 16):

In simple, **rudimentary**, terms...

- A **dot** is the smallest possible spot of **ink** on paper.
- A **pixel** is the smallest possible spot of **light** on a screen.

Dots are *never* on a screen and pixels are *never* on paper.

---

This **does not** cover how pixels are *made*. Nor does it cover how ink is *made*. If you care about construction of either, then a *rudimentary* explanation is another matter, especially where pixels are concerned since they are intangible and not a *physical* object, unlike dots/ink.

Upon *output* (printing) pixels are *translated*, via mathematical formulas, to dots. Such formulas *could* mean 1 pixel = 2 dots or 2 pixel = 1 dot or 1 pixel = 15 dots... there's no *direct* correlation between pixel and dot. It's the output formula which determines how a given number of pixels *may* relate to dots.

Comment: Then how do you explain a monitor's "*dot* pitch"?

Comment: @CodyGray, well this site is about *graphic design* and the meaning of the word Scott describes is directly linked to a graphic designer's work and part of the terminology a graphic designer should know. How a monitor is constructed is vaguely related and interesting enough, but not really something a graphic designer normally worries about.

Comment: I think that "this site is about graphic design" is a poor justification for offering an incomplete and/or misleading definition of a word. Even if it's true that graphic designers primarily (or exclusively?) use the word "dot" to refer to ink on a printed page, a good answer to the question should, *at a minimum*, call out the fact that other usages exist. It is also a bit silly in the modern age to pretend that "graphic design" might be somehow limited to print media. Many designers work exclusively on graphics that will be displayed on monitors. @Wolff

Comment: @CodyGray, yes I realize that much graphic design end up being displayed on monitors. I just fail to see how a designer can use knowledge about dot pitch to aid them in their design decisions. Also there are also other meanings of the word "dot" that are related to graphic design. I mean a little blob or the dot over an "i" for example. I just felt it would confuse to include all meanings. But perhaps you are right that this site should contain a complete answer that covers all aspects of the pixel/dot confusion. We still don't have that yet - even after this question. 

Comment: Question asks for **rudimentary** explanation, not a detailed explanation regarding the intricacies of the inner working of displays and how they operate in order to create/display a pixel. I didn't explain how to create ink either.

Comment: @CodyGray density of a monitor is mostly irrelevant to authors. It does not affect anything, most displays just show one pixel as one pixel. And its not like i can specify what monitor to use. So only time a graphic designer is interested in this is for print. For screen consumption you use other methods.

Comment: @CodyGray For CRT monitors, "dot pitch" is a term of art with a specific technical meaning; "dot" in that context cannot be interpreted as it is when used in other contexts. For the details of what dot pitch is, [see this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/154702/147841).

Comment: @CodyGray From Google... *The term "dot pitch" refers to the distance between like-colored phosphors on a video monitor.* This means the space *between* pixels, rather than a comparison of the size of print dots to pixels.

Comment: As regards a display screen, a dot is the smallest physical point of light that can be produced by the hardware. A pixel is the smallest unit of image data that can be projected on a screen. A pixel on a screen will more than likely will be made up of multiple dots, and not necessarily in a one-to-one ratio.

Comment: By "output", in your last paragraph, do you mean "printing"? Because if not, I have no idea what you're trying to say there. (And if you do, I'd like to suggest clarifying it. At least as I've learned to understand the word, "output" in the context of computing means transferring data out of a computer system or a part thereof, and in that process converting it into a form that the user, or some external hardware or software, can observe and make sense of. This does include printing, but also e.g. displaying a picture on a screen or even playing audio on a speaker.)

Comment: @AgentBiscutt: No - the dot pitch is unrelated to the size of pixels displayed...

Comment: @psmears Yah, I had said that it was the space __*between*__ pixels, rather than the actual size of the pixels. Sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: @AgentBiscutt: The dot pitch is not related to the space between pixels, either... there can be many, many dots making up one pixel (eg when displaying a low-resolution mode on a high-resolution CRT).

Comment: I find it humorous that everyone's throwing in their 2¢ about pixels, how they are made, what comprises them.. yet no one feels the need to explain what a dot of ink is.. how it's made, variations.... `:)` I think the word "rudimentary" has been lost by a few `:)`

Answer (score 6):

This is more like a long comment than a answer.

The reason why you fail to get this is simply you have no need for this information. The only way you can ever understand this is if you care about the actual technical implementation details of the underlying system. In this case a printer and a screen. Since you most likely live in a all digital world you will likely never get it nor does knowing this benefit you at all.

Human language is not fixed enough that the definition of a dot is so definitive that you can not say a screen does not contain dots. The definitions of the words depend on context, audience etc. Most humans dont write academically correct language at all times. In fact they can not as the meaning of the word dot and pixel varies depending on what academic field they would follow some persons might need to cross fields. In fact monitor manufacturers sometimes call technical elemens of pixels dots.

But they are indeed different. Its just that dividing something into only two categories is a bit misleading. There are several different ways to implement screens and several ways to implement printers. Lumping them all under pixels and dots is a bit arbitrary. But as long as you talk of:

- Laser printers and offset printers
- Most generic color screens

Then it is ok to divide them in two categories. But just be aware that once you start talking about inkjets, or some exotic system like chemical or heat based printing it becomes increasingly harder to keep up the appearances that this nomlencature makes sense.

So roughly speaking saying that a dot is printed and a pixel is on screen is prudent. But i dont like that definition as it lacks predictive value. I would much rather point to the fact that we mentally treat them differently. For some reason we treat a pixel as whole all included in one even if the color channels are separate sub pixels, and may in fact be grouped in some wierd stochastic clumping. This leads to:

- A pixel has any amount of intensity in all 3 colors
- While a dot has one intensity, on or off one color.

So they do not compare very well. A pixel is more like a group of dots (called a halftone screen), so its disengenious to compare dots of a printer to pixels of a screen. Its much more honest to compare a pixel to the size of your halftone. But then that wouldn't allow so much marketting bulshit to happen.

Comment: *"a dot has one intensity, on or off one color"* I don't believe that to be universally correct. Continuous tone printing technologies such as dye sublimation can have multiple color intensities in one position (a "dot") without recourse to dithering / screening.

Comment: @abligh yes, and that is why, i definined all of this only to apply to laser and offset printers. Like i said the further you walk out of that definition the less the dot-pixel divide becomes useful.

Comment: So what do we call one "dot" in a screen (screens consists of dots right)? I would always say it a pixel before.

Comment: @Vikas some do some dont generally you dont have a y need to go beyond subpixel level. We call it a dot, but you need to be clear what you mean. You can not mix usage in one discussion or people will get mighty confused. For a graphic designer the internal structure of a monitor is rarely relevant in any way.

Comment: I guess the word pixel has multiple meanings depending on the profession, then.

Comment: @Vikas its not exactly my fault that graphic designers use the term pixel for three different things.

Answer (score 2):

In the beginning, there was no difference between a dot and a pixel - the two terms were interchangeable.  That's why you still encounter the term DPI in contexts where they're clearly referring to PPI.  Even on a CRT where it was clear that a single pixel lit up a varying amount of phosphor dots, nobody bothered to draw the distinction.

As technology progressed, clever people figured out that you could subdivide a pixel to provide variations on pixel brightness.  A pixel subdivided into dots where half the dots are dark and half are light would look like it was at a 50% intensity.  "Bit depth" is how you describe the number of possible variations of intensity; for example 8 bits allows for 256 different levels of intensity, because that's the number of unique values you can represent with 8 binary digits.

I think you already understand the "per inch" part of the equation.  As the density of elements per inch goes up, whether they be dots or pixels, the sharper your image will appear.

Comment: Even in the beginning dot and pixel were *not* the same thing. The difference was that people didn't care *how* pixels were formed or what any difference was -- either dot or pixel were/are the smallest possible unit/element... now there are entire industries vested in how they create a pixel and the general public is far, far, far, more educated about pixels. But... dot and pixel have really never been the "same thing".

Comment: @Scott I suppose it depends on what you consider the beginning.  I'm talking about a time before the web, before ink-jet printers.  If you weren't around back then you'll just have to take my word for it.

Comment: I was around... started *by hand* and saw the birth of the first Mac. `:)` Dot and pixel were never the same.. people just didn't care about the actual difference.

Comment: @Scott what makes you think the Mac was the beginning?  I did graphics in the 1970's with an electrostatic plotter which could do either 100 or 200 DPI.  You'll notice that I said DPI, because that was the term in common use at the time; nobody talked about pixels.

Comment: Didn't say Mac *was* the beginning.. said I saw the first one :)

Answer (score 1):

Some units are very precisely defined. Others much less. And you'll learn that some can have very different definitions depending on context or whoever you're talking to.

Supposedly, a **pixel** (**pict**ure **el**ement) is the smallest addressable unit on a **screen**. So your screen may have 1920 x 1080 pixels ("full HD"), with each pixel being able to have a different color. But RGB pixels are actually made of 3 elements (**sub-pixels**), one for each **channel**: one **red**, one **green**, one **blue** (sometimes one is doubled). And some technologies (e.g. ClearType) will actually use those subpixels individually to take advantage of the higher resolution for anti-aliasing purposes (this requires knowing how the sub-pixels are arranged, and in what order).

Some people will tell you each of those sub-pixels are dots. Others won't and tell you the pixels are dots. Some people (a minority, though) will even tell you that each of the sub-pixels are actually the pixels (this is most common coming from the actual display manufacturers).

It is worth noting that screens can vary the intensity of each sub-pixel. This is where the **bits per channel** come in. Each sub pixel is not just on (full red, green or blue) or off (black) — this would only give us a total of 8 colours: black, red, green, blue, yellow (red+green), purple (red+blue), cyan (green+blue) and white (red+green+blue).

Instead, each sub-pixel (channel) can take a number of values between the two. If you have **8 bits per channel** (so a total of 24 bits for RGB), that means **each of those sub pixels can take 256 different values** (1 bit = 2 values, 2 bits = 4 values, 3 bits = 8 values, and you continue doubling until 8 bits = 256 values). So **in total, you get 256 x 256 x 256 = 16 million colours**.

---

The **dot** is more commonly used in **print**. Initially, on black-and-white printers, where each dot can only have two states: it is white (no print/no ink) or black (print/ink).

Note that on printers (especially inkjet printers), dots can be larger than the spacing between them and overlap (usually the opposite for pixels, which if you look very very closely may have a bit of space between them), though of course older dot matrix printers usually had spaces between dots.

Contrary to screens, **printers usually don't handle anything but on or off** (printed or not, ink deposited on the paper or not). You can't get a half-printed dot. So to get grayscale, or a large variety of colours, one will use patterns (called **halftones**). To have something quite dark, you set most dots to black. To have something quite light, you'll set only a few. Likewise to get any colour you want, you'll combine multiple patterns on top of each other, one each for cyan, magenta and yellow (and usually black for best results).

If you look at large billboards e.g. in subway stations, which are produced by expanding a smaller image, you'll see those patterns quite clearly.

To achieve the same kind of results you would on a screen (in terms of number of colours), you thus need multiple dots for each individual unit you want to assign a different colour to. For instance, if you want to have the same 8 bits per channel, you need to be able to print anywhere between 0 and 255 ink dots for each unit. That requires 256 dots, or a square of 16 x 16 dots.

Note that you may think that 8 dots are enough, with each dot matching one bit, but that's not the case. In an 8-bit channel, each bit has a different weight, while all the dots have the same weight. So you need a lot more.

This means that if all those dots where arranged in a perfectly rectangular fashion, you need 16 times more dots in each direction to achieve the same result as a screen (in term of number of colours). That's one of the reasons why **professional printing usually uses resolutions of about 1200 or 2400 dots per inch**. In the end, this is not much better (for pictures) than a screen at 75 to 150 dpi (but it makes a whole lot of a difference for cases where you're printing pure black and white, like text, because you don't use halftones for those). The resolution once you take into account the pattern size is measured in... **lines per inch**.

This is the reason why, in print, in you want a specific colour but also need fine detail, you won't print in regular CMYK, but actually have a separate channel using a predefined colour with will use a specific ink. So if you want very readable purple text, you won't print it as a combination of cyan and magenta (which will give a very fine grid of dots mixing the two, and you'll end up with "fuzzy" text), but directly using purple ink. That's where Pantone colours and other palettes come in, they're actually inks (of course this is for professional offset printing, usually not on your home laser printer which can only use the standard inks).

You'll notice that I mentioned **"dots per inch" (dpi) both for printers and for screens**. Yes, "dots per inch" for screens are actually pixels per inch. Same thing for your screen's "dot pitch".

---

If that wasn't complex enough, some units also have standardised **sizes**. As for a long time computer screens had vaguely similar resolutions (in dots per inch) usually in the 70-90 dpi range, programmers often measured things in pixels rather than more absolute units like points (1/72 of an inch), mm, cm, picas, or whatnot.

The problem? When higher-resolution screens (e.g. the "Retina" screens) came along, anything that was measured in pixels would become a lot smaller if the relationship with the physical pixel was maintained, not the intended effect.

So some technologies (like CSS) **define a pixel as being something which is not a physical screen pixel! They actually define it as 1/96 of an inch**.

This gives quite interesting discussions between CSS pixels and actual physical pixels. [This page](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions) for instance will show you the difference between "points" used by programmers/designers (which are not actual 1/72 inch points, and in the context of CSS, are the same as CSS pixels), rendered pixels (using an integer ratio), physical pixels (after bit of downsampling the match the actual number of screen pixels) and physical size.

Welcome to the wonderful world of pixels and dots!